# How to replace WebRequest with HttpClient in .NET 4.8 with the ability to change request headers each time

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webrequest, .net-4.8

So I have a script that sends requests with the `WebRequest` class.
I want to change it to use `HttpClient` class.

It is recommended to have a singleton `HttpClient` class because calling it multiple times might exhaust the socket pool.
But having `HttpClient` as singleton would mean I couldn't change the header information of a request each time. And I want to change the headers each time.

How would I implement a singleton `HttpClient` class with the ability to change the request headers each time?

Comment: `I couldn't change the header information of a request each time.` that's not the case at all. As the name says, an HttpClient is a *client* not an individual request. You can set default headers for all calls made with that client, eg API keys. Each request can have different headers though

Comment: how can each request have individual headers ? Could you please provide some links I can refer ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-6.0) class.

Example for a POST request:

```
using HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage();
msg.RequestUri = new Uri("...");
msg.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
msg.Headers.Add("x-my-custom-header", 123);
msg.Content = new StringContent("some string content");

await httpClient.SendAsync(msg, cancellationToken);
```